# Datatables: pagination not updating after server processing

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Datatables to display a tonne of info on a web app I am building. However, even though all filtering, searching, etc is working perfectly, my pagination is not updating whatsoever. It seems to think that it only has 1 page, even though I can get more data from the server consistently. Is this something that should happen natively, or do I need to update my pagination or redraw it each time the data changes?

Comment: Can you post some of you code? Really tough to hazard a guess in terms of what is wrong without it...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the problem was caused by server side code that was never shared. Not likely to help future visitors.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed this yesterday, meant to update it earlier. There was an issue with the server code where the correct number of rows wasn't being brought back for the total record vals.